# ng-repeat variable not getting sent into controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat that takes data from a JSON call and builds several widgets on the page. Each widget has a form button which is suppose to grab the id and name of the data object that generated the selected widget.

`{{term.term}}` compiles to `"tablets"` in the HTML.

However in my Controller the terms that it reads is `{{term.term}}` instead of `"tablets"`

---

```
<div ng-repeat="term in terms"
     class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 term-section">

    <div class="term_tag">
        <a href="" ng-click="ticker.openTagModal('{{term.term}}')">
            <div class="tag">
                {{term.term}}
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

The HTML in the Chrome inspector looks like:
[image]

Now the openTagModal function in my Controller:

```
// Open the edit account modal:
this.openTagModal = function(term) {
    console.log('term = '+term);
    $scope.main.modal_terms = true;
    $scope.main.modal = true;
};
```

^ Here term should = "tablets" but instead it reads this:
[image]

Any idea why this is happening? I'm not using a `Directive` yet, just an `ng-repeat` div, could that be it?

Comment: I think you want `ng-click="ticker.openTagModal(term.term)"`

Comment: Ah you are right! Want to post the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the braces in the `ng-click` directive e.g:

`ng-click="ticker.openTagModal(term.term)"`

The `ng-click` directive takes an angular expression. Angular expressions in HTML are normally wrapped in `{{}}` to define them as expressions, however you don't need them for `ng-click` as it's already assumed to take an expression.